# How to switch lightdm-gtk-greeter to use wayland only? (x11 not installed)

Tags: fedora, configuration, wayland, lightdm, lightdm-gtk-greeter

I'm on a Fedora Server 37 iso, so no DM/DE is pre-installed.

1. Install wayland, lightdm, and lightdm-gtk-greeter.
2. Edit lightdm's config to use lightdm-gtk-greeter

   - (Line 102) change `greeter-session=example-gtk-gnome` to `greeter-session=lightdm-gtk-greeter`
   - (Line 107) change `user-session=default` to `user-session=qtile`
3. Try to start graphical.target, and it fails.

- From `sudo tail -n100 /var/log/lightdm/lightdm.log`, here's a chunk of the relevant part. It tries to start an xserver, even though I don't have one installed and want to use wayland instead. I can't find a config option to tell it to use wayland either. Did I miss it, or is there another way to do this?

  ```
  [+0.00s] DEBUG: Using D-Bus name org.freedesktop.DisplayManager
  [+0.00s] DEBUG: _g_io_module_get_default: Found default implementation local (GLocalVfs) for ‘gio-vfs’
  [+0.00s] DEBUG: Using cross-namespace EXTERNAL authentication (this will deadlock if server is GDBus < 2.73.3)
  [+0.00s] DEBUG: Monitoring logind for seats
  [+0.00s] DEBUG: New seat added from logind: seat0
  [+0.00s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Loading properties from config section Seat:*
  [+0.00s] DEBUG: Seat seat0 has property CanMultiSession=no
  [+0.00s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Starting
  [+0.00s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Creating greeter session
  [+0.00s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Creating display server of type x
  [+0.00s] DEBUG: Using VT 1
  [+0.00s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Starting local X display on VT 1
  [+0.00s] DEBUG: XServer 0: Logging to /var/log/lightdm/x-0.log
  [+0.00s] DEBUG: XServer 0: Can't launch X server X -core -noreset, not found in path
  [+0.00s] DEBUG: XServer 0: X server stopped
  [+0.00s] DEBUG: Releasing VT 1
  [+0.00s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Display server stopped
  [+0.00s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Can't create display server for greeter
  [+0.00s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Session stopped
  [+0.00s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Stopping display server, no sessions require it
  [+0.00s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Stopping
  [+0.00s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Stopped
  [+0.00s] DEBUG: Failed to start seat: seat0
  ```

Edit: [This github issue](https://github.com/canonical/lightdm/issues/268#issue-1382510272) is someone's log that gets a lot farther than I do. My log above, you see `Seat seat0: Creating display server of type x`, but theirs is `type wayland`. This is the main thing I'd like to figure out. However later in their log, they call `/etc/lightdm/Xsession ...` still too. Is there a way to install a tiny subset of x11 to work, or do I need an entire x server package along with wayland to get LightDM running?

Comment: Maybe these two will help: https://www.reddit.com/r/antergos/comments/9h7grw/how_to_wayland_with_lightdm/ - https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/LightDM

Comment: **With the redit link**: I've done the equivalent for steps 1-4. (I have a `qtile.desktop` inside wayland-sessions). Step 5 doesn't happen since it fails to start. :/

**With the archlinux link**: section 4 seemed promising. I was missing the `xorg-x11-server-Xephyr` package. It still gives the same error though. But I'm surprised it says "run LightDM as an X application", I thought the point of wayland was to avoid x11.

Comment: That Wiki page explains both X and Wayland, hence that. You're not stumbling on 6.14?

Comment: lightdm doesn't support Wayland, your question makes no sense. It can start Wayland sessions but it cannot be run/used as a pure Wayland application.

Comment: @Peregrino69 yes, it's a fresh install so I have nothing in the xsessions dir, only wayland-sessions.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Thank you! I just added an edit at the end to gear the question towards that. Do you mean lightdm itself, so no greeter can do this? Or specifically lightdm-gtk-greeter? I'm surprised you'd want both installed.

Comment: GDM can run in pure Wayland mode. The only Wayland DM AFAIK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> or do I need an entire x server package along with wayland to get LightDM running?

LightDM requires the full featured Xorg server.

You may want to install GDM, the [only](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/wayland#Display_managers) display manager which works in pure Wayland mode as of April, 2023.

Addendum: Fedora 38 contains a GIT version of SDDM which can work in Wayland mode as well. There's also an [sddm-git](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/sddm-git) Wayland enabled package in Arch.